# Cannot watch a running log file

Tags: python, bash, unix

I have a simple python program, **sample.py**:

```
import time
n = 1
while True:
    print 'Testing', n
    n += 1
    time.sleep (1)
```

When I run the program in bash as a background job:

```
$ python sample.py &> sample.log &
```

Now watch the log file:

```
$ watch tail -n5 sample.log
```

I don't see anything unless the program is stopped. Also, if view the **sample.log** file in any text editor, its empty.

So, how can I view the changes in the log file in real-time?

Comment: Try just using `tail -f -n5 sample.log`, the `-f` flag means to follow the file as it changes.

Comment: [Does this help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/107717/5067311)?

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not work. It seems that I can see the whole sample.log file once the program terminated. It shouldn't be the behavior though. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Output gets buffered; flush the buffer after each print, and you'll see your `watch` command produce the expected output.

```
import time
import sys

n = 1
while True:
    print 'Testing', n
    sys.stdout.flush()
    n += 1
    time.sleep (1)
```